# C# Unity Sound plays when pressing 'Play' without reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class SoundPlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    int countSound = 0;
    public AudioSource sound;

    void Update()
    {
        if(TimerCountdown.FinishCheck && !(sound.isPlaying) && countSound < 3)
        {
            sound.Play();
            countSound += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I'm doing here is, when a boolean value hits true, the sound starts playings 3 times ( that's about 5 seconds after letting it run ). However, I don't understand why, when I press PLAY, the sound plays 1 time randomly. Why is that? Surelly the `if statement`  is not true because of the `countSound = 0` at first. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the `AudioSource` for Play On Awake?

Comment: Stupid me. Yeah that was it. Sorry I'm literally a newbie with Unity, and I'm trying to figure how stuff works without any tutorials. Thank you so much for help!